# Scanned Pdf documents do not print every now and then with Brother MFC-J6930DW

Tags: pdf, cups, printer, brother

I have the Brother MFC-J6930DW printer. Documents can be printed with Linux Mint without problems. PDF's created from documents are also no problem to print. If I want to print a scanned document, the print fails for some documents.

Printing stands for a long time (> 20 minutes) in the printer queue and also on the printer. The remedy is to cancel the document in the printer queue and to disconnect the printer from the power supply.

With Windows I can print the document. However, this also takes some time.

Printing is done via the network (Lan). Unfortunately I have no idea how to get to the bottom of the problem. In some cases it helps if I strongly compress the PDF document. However, the quality is also affected. I use the standard printer drivers that come with Cups. I can't print at all with the Brother drivers.